# UILabel is not getting created when the app loads for first time- IOS

Tags: ios, null, uilabel, variable-assignment

I have a problem with UILabel being not assigned with Text, when the app loads up. There are two methods **updateDateLabel** and **updateTitleLabel** (which will assign two different labels) that'l be called when the app loads first time and number of times again after loading the app based on user request.

```
- (void)updateDateLabel {
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
outputFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm MM-dd-YY";
_dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"as of: %@", [outputFormatter stringFromDate:_refreshDateTime]];
[_dateLabel setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

```
-(void)updateTitleLabel {
_selectedProfileData = [_balanceData objectAtIndex:_selectedProfile];
if ([NSNull null] != [_selectedProfileData objectForKey:@"advProfileName"]) {
    NSString *name = [_selectedProfileData objectForKey:@"advProfileName"];
    _titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Balances", name];
    [_titleLabel setNeedsDisplay];
} else {
    _titleLabel.text = @"QuickView Balances";
    [_titleLabel setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

}

The thing is, it should display **QuickView Balances as of:** when the app loads for the first time, but whats happening is it is displaying **(nulls)'s Balances as of:(null)**.

My guess is that the labels are not being created when these methods are called for the first time, Can anyone help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Where, exactly, are you calling `updateTitleLabel`? `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.?

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to add the method. i'm calling these methods from **requestDidFinishLoading** when the app loads for the first time (only once) and from **viewWillAppear** after the app loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `[_selectedProfileData objectForKey:@"advProfileName"]` is null. Check with

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_selectedProfileData objectForKey:@"advProfileName"]);
```

You will see `(null)`. For test if your value is null just do

```
if([_selectedProfileData objectForKey:@"advProfileName"] != nil)
```

or just

```
if([_selectedProfileData objectForKey:@"advProfileName"])
```

You don't need to call `setNeedsDisplay` and if you see something at the screen, the labels are created.